# Curl Post request to upload .zip file to Sharepoint returning "Compressed (zipped) folder invalid when downloading

Tags: rest, curl, sharepoint, upload, zip

I have a curl Post request that attempts to upload the latest documents to our Sharepoint. It appears to work fine, the file I send is valid and opens fine before I send it. Once it arrives on sharepoint the filesize is the same but when I download it appears to be corrupted and wont open.

I have tried manually uploading the zip file to Sharepoint, it works fine this way.

I have also scanned the internet for some solution to the problem but I am unable to find anything.

> curl -X POST
>   "http://12.3.456.78:8080/TEST-2.0/sharepoint?relativePath=Shared%20Documents%2FRelease%20Documents%2Fv1&teamSite=Test"
>   -H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@Test.zip;type=application/x-zip-compressed"

I expect the file on sharepoint to be valid and open correctly after download but I get the following error.

"Windows cannot open the folder.

The Compressed (zipped) Folder 'C:\Test.zip' is invalid.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was within the code, although the file was sending, it was obviously not sending correctly which was causing the corruption.

The line that I added that made the difference was the following.

```
post.setEntity( new FileEntity(file) );
```

My full method can be found below, feel free to comment if anyone needs further information on this in the future.

```
    public HttpResponse uploadFile( String teamSite,
                                String relativePath,
                                String accessToken,
                                File file ) throws IOException
{
    String fileName = null;
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

    fileName = file.getName().replaceAll( " ", "%20" );
    relativePath = relativePath.replaceAll( " ", "%20" );
    teamSite = teamSite.replaceAll( " ", "%20" );

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost( URL );
    post.setHeader( "Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose" );
    post.setHeader( "Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken );
    post.setEntity( new FileEntity(file) ); //This line here
    HttpResponse response = client.execute( post );
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    String responseString = EntityUtils.toString( entity, "UTF-8" );

    return response;
}
```